# How do I use DAX to filter a fact table where a value in one dimension table is greater than a value in a different dimension table

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a fact table with two linked dimension tables.
I am trying to write a DAX filter that filters the fact table based on whether a date in one dimension table is greater than

Something along the lines of this (although obviously this doesn't work).

```
CALCULATE ( SUM ( factFinancial[Value] ), dimOne[Date1] > dimTwo[Date2] )
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to answer without a specific example to work with but I suspect you can find a solution along these lines:

```
CALCULATE (
    SUM ( factFinancial[Value] ),
    FILTER ( factFinancial, RELATED ( dimOne[Date1] ) > RELATED ( dimTwo[Date2] ) )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

The calculate function can not evaluate your expression, The reasons are:

1. During its evaluation algorithm, CALCULATE cannot determine whether the condition should replace any existing filter on dimOne [Date1], on dimTwo [Date2], or on none of them.
2. Row context does not interact automatically with relationships, means that the expression dimOne[Date1] > dimTwo[Date2] is evaluated in row context and the two columns [Date1] and [Date2] are from two different tables, there since we cannot access the corresponding date from [Date2] to each date on [Date1] automatically. In this situation you must use RELATED and RELATEDTABLE DAX functions.

In order to achieve your aim you must use **filter** and **RELATED** functions.

Use this code  instead to create the measure in factFinancial table :

```
CALCULATE(SUM (factFinancial[Value]), 
FILTER(factFinancial,RELATED(dimOne[Date1]) > RELATED(dimTwo[Date2])))
```

Visit : https://www.sqlbi.com/blog/marco/2010/01/03/how-calculate-works-in-dax/

Visit : https://www.microsoftpressstore.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2449191&seqNum=5